# python raw string assignment

Tags: python, string, sqlobject

Given a file contains lines such as:

```
(?i:\bsys\.user_catalog\b)
```

While reading those line, I want the value to be a raw string (unescaped), meaning, in memory, line should be

```
r'(?i:\bsys\.user_catalog\b)'
```

instead of

```
(?i:\bsys\.user_catalog\b)
```

Which is escaped when passed over to libs such as sqlobject.

For instance, with sqlobject, if I state

```
Table(column=r'(?i:\bsys\.user_catalog\b)')
```

I get the desired results while if I state

```
Table(column='(?i:\bsys\.user_catalog\b)')
```

I do not.

So question is basically, I can I pass a raw string when I am not in declarative/assignment mode (e.g. `a = r'string'`), rather,  the string is already in memory.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The raw string notation is only used in Python source code; all strings declared as raw strings are "converted" to normal strings with the necessary escape sequences added during "compile time" (unlike (in Python 2) the two different string types string/Unicode string):

```
>>> r"\b"
'\\b'
>>> "Hello"
'Hello' 
>>> u"Hello"
u'Hello'
```

If you read the string from a file, it will already be correctly escaped.

(Assuming `test.txt` contains `(?i:\bsys\.user_catalog\b)`):

```
f = open("test.txt").read()
print f
print repr(f)
```

Output:

```
(?i:\bsys\.user_catalog\b)
'(?i:\\bsys\\.user_catalog\\b)'
```

Comment: "If you read the string from a file, it will already be correctly escaped." This is somewhat misleading; more accurately, the concept of "escaping" doesn't apply to a string **object** but only to a string **literal**. If you read one backslash from a file, you get a string with one backslash in it. If you write `"\\"`, you get a string with one backslash in it. The escaping only happens in the source code so that there is a clear way to say what's part of the string and what's part of the rest of the code. Once the string object is created, that's already clear.

Comment: Similarly, raw strings aren't "converted"; they're an *alternate syntax* for creating *the same type of object*.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: Thanks for the clarification. I wish I could have written it like this :)

Comment: Python2 is still python

Answer (score 3):

You can use raw string anywhere you are using a string. Raw string is just a user friendly way to represent a string when you have lots of escape characters.

The second case is not working because of the `'\'`. So you need to escape it using another `'\'`. The second case should work if you give `'(?i:\\bsys\\.user_catalog\\b)'`. In memory, since ASCII or Unicode is stored, it doesn't make any difference if it is raw string or not.

Comment: this still not helping me, as I need to pass the raw string to sqlobject

Comment: There is no such thing as a "raw string type" you could pass. They are, as M S correctly noted, pure syntactic sugar for the programmer's convenience.

Answer (score 2):

You are thinking about this the wrong way. There isn't a "raw string" type, only "string". Writing `r` in front of the quotes only tells python how to interpret the following string.

http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals